# If (Internet == unavailable) in HTML5 app manifest offiline app

Tags: javascript, html5-appcache, offline-caching

I want to put condition for login page that if an internet connection is available, then check the server database, otherwise check the localstorage.

I have tried to check this via an AJAX call, but when the page is loaded from the appcache, it always shows me that I'm connected to the Internet. I know a little about fallback section in the manifest file, but I don't know how to use it in my case.

What should I do to handle events when offline?

Comment: Define "available". This is not necessarily easy. Sometimes it's just plain broken, but the problem is when it's technically working, but unusably slow.

Comment: `but when the page is loaded from the appcache, it always shows me that I'm connected to the Internet` your ajax response is cached.

Answer (score 7):

You could easily pull the client's internet status by using `Navigator.onLine` which returns a boolean.

```
if (!navigator.onLine) {
   //Browser is offline, pull data from localStorage
} else {
   //Browser is online, pull data through AJAX
}
```

You could also bind it to an event listener, so that you can change the data source on the fly:

```
window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) { 
   //Browser is offline, pull data from localStorage
});
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

At the time of posting, [this function is supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status) on IE11, IE Edge, Firefox 51+ Chrome 49+, Safari 10+, iOS 9.3+, Android Browser 4.4+ and Chrome for Android 57+

---

**Update** It appears that I misunderstood your original question. After checking your manifest file. The code to pull the data from localStorage should go into the `FALLBACK` section. You should place your localStorage function into the `offline.html` file.

```
FALLBACK:
/ offline.html
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Comment: @Bharat Show us how you implemented it, paste your code into jsfiddle and paste the link here :) the function above works, we are using it in many HTML webapps. Am sure it's just some implementation quirks. Let us take a look.

Comment: Sure. https://jsfiddle.net/bharats/61bxtvhy/15/
I have put Manifest in HTML section. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer. The browser when it detects the user is offline, will call the files from the section declared in `FALLBACK`. That is where you should place your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142681/discussion-between-bharat-and-james-wong).